# iOS - White gap on right side after pushing view controller

Tags: ios, iphone

So pretty much on my iPhone 5 running iOS 7.1.1, when I push a view controller after the initial view controller, it leaves a 1 pixel white gap on the right side and I can't figure out why for the life of me why its doing that!

Initial view controller image:

[image]

Pushed view controller image:

[image]

PS. it doesn't do it on my iPhone 4 running iOS 7.1.2 and my iPhone 5, 6 and 6 plus running iOS 8 and above!

Comment: Are you using Autolayout? Is your image laid out properly? You very likely have an error in the resource definition or the layout. Code sample?

Comment: Please add more information about how you setup your views and do you use Auto-layout. the background of the second view controller is an image or a color ? how did you setup it up if it's a color or an image?

Comment: Not going to provide code due to contractual reasons but, yes it is using auto layout, and the background of the second view is a colour, however the gap to the right will ALWAYS be right no matter what the content to the left of it is.

Comment: Basically I could have a bunch of blank view controllers with different colour backgrounds, and when they start presenting each other, any view controller after the first one will have a white gap on the right side